# I want to add a button, which ,when tapped, will show the user the list of contacts in his/her iPhone. Please help me find some working API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, addressbook, abaddressbook

i have already searched many places
many people have used ABAddressBookRef class
but my xcode 4 does not recognize this
i have imported 
and i have added the library/framework too
but still the code was not recognized
please help me in finding some working functions/classes/APIs which i call and they do there task
THANK YOU EVERYONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController....

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Answer (score 1):

[The AddressBook API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html) should do what you need. Use the IBAction or gesture link to the button to present it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use AddressBook framework, first add the refrence to the framework,

Then import AddressBook.h in your class

`#import "AddressBook/AddressBook.h"`

Then start using `ABAddressBookRef`

`ABAddressBookRef ref;`